# How to install and execute Blender 2.79 on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: software-installation, raspberrypi, blender

I'm trying to install Blender 2.79, as I think it's the last version that is fully functional with my version of OpenGL.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04. I can install blender through `sudo apt-get install blender`, but it will not run, outputting "A graphics card and driver with support for OpenGL 3.3 or higher is required. The program will now close."

I've downloaded every package with the word "linux" on [the official download page](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/), after unzipping the files (tar -xf filename) and navigating into the directories they download, running `./blender` outputs "bash: ./blender: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error".

Doing the same with the source packages from [Ubuntu Packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/blender-data), the terminal outputs "bash: ./blender: No such file or directory".

How do I install a working version of blender on Ubuntu with a Raspberry Pi 4?

Comment: It is available as a [snap](https://snapcraft.io/blender). Maybe the snap doesn't work on this architecture? I would not expect acceptable performance on a raspberry pi.

Comment: Installing the snap results in a message stating that blender isn't available for this (arm64) architecture. In case you were wondering, articles and posts such as these lead me to believe that installing this should be possible.
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/10/install-blender-ubuntu-complete-guide/                                                     https://www.tomshardware.com/news/raspberry-pi-3d-modeling-blender-how             https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/124617/i-would-like-to-install-blender-on-my-raspberry-pi4

Comment: AFAIK, the snap is the only way to get this version. The release archives that you linked do not contain anything for the arm64 architecture. It's possible that you might find an unsupported way to do this, but even if you can technically install blender on a raspi, it's not going to be very useful on that hardware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem, and with the results of extended searches I have found out that is not possible to run Blender on the Raspberry Pi at least not with current OS's like Ubuntu 22.04 (with Blender 3.0 in the repositories) or even Debian 11 Bullseye that comes with Blender 2.93.

There are no Snap, Flatpak or AppImage for ARM64 Architecture (i.e. Raspberry Pi).

Using Box64 emulator generate errors and the programs aborts.

The only workarounds I have found are:

1. Compiling Blender 2.79 from source (Blender 2.79 uses OpenGL 3.1 which is supported by the VideoCore VI on the Raspberry Pi 4), but there are no instructions on how to compile for ARM architecture.  The source code for 2.79 can be downloaded from here: https://download.blender.org/source/
2. It is possible to force Blender 3.0 to run on the Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu 22.04 by using the following override for Mesa, by running this on the command line:

   ```
   MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3 blender
   ```

It has its drawbacks: your model is shown with graphical glitches and trying to make a rendered preview using Eevee rendering engine freezes Blender